# Searching through output of more command

Tags: regex

When searching through the output of more command how can I search for a phrase that includes spaces in between? When I search for a phrase like "typedef struct audiodev" it doesn't find the phrase in the file and I'm assuming this is because I need to express the space between the words with a certain symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regexp to match spaces:

```
egrep 'typedef\s+struct\s+audiodev' your_file
```

Here `\s+` corresponds to one or more spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the command more with other tools like grep.

Open a console and try:

```
more yourfile | grep "typedef struct audiodev"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the search function of `more`, spaces (all special characters actually) need to be [escaped](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/escapingsection.html), so you could search like this:

```
/typedef\ struct\ audiodev
```